# How to edit Sysconfig file using batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

My Sysconfig file looks like below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <appSettings>
    <MESCustomMenuID value="" />
  </appSettings>
  </configuration>
```

I want to change tag value

```
<MESCustomMenuID value="" /> to <MESCustomMenuID value="SOLUMTE" />
```

I tried below coding to change tag value

```
@echo off
set CWD=%~dp0

set _FilePath=C:\Epicor\ERPDT\Client-Pilot\config\
set _FileName=Default - Copy.sysconfig

set _WrkFile=Default - Copy_bak.xml
set OldStr="<MESCustomMenuID value="" />"
set NewStr="<MESCustomMenuID value="SOLUTMES" />"


set _Found=Not found

SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%_FilePath%%_WrkFile%") do (
    set _LineChk=%%a
    if "!_LineChk!"==%OldStr% (
        SET _Found=Found 
        SET NewStr=!NewStr:^"=! 
        echo !NewStr!
        ::echo ^<MESCustomMenuID value="SOLUTMES"^>
        ) else (echo %%a)
        )>>"%_FilePath%%_FileName%" 2>&1
```

The code above is collapsed sysconfig file XML tags

Comment: The task can be done with [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) with the single command line `jrepl.bat "(<MESCustomMenuID[\t ]+value=\x22)[^\x22]*" "$1SOLUTMES" /F "C:\Epicor\ERPDT\Client-Pilot\config\Default - Copy.sysconfig" /O "Copy.sysconfig"` independent on which string is currently assigned to attribute `value` of XML element `MESCustomMenuID `. __JREPL.BAT__ is a BAT/JScript hybrid doing the regular expression replace with JScript using Windows Script Host (`cscript.exe` in this case). `\x22` is `"` with its hexadecimal value.

Comment: Yes i did working Mofi working thanks